# Showing that $Tp(x)=(1-x^2)p''(x)-2xp'(x) $ is self-adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, inner-products, adjoint-operators

Let $P_2(\Bbb{R})$ have the inner product $\langle p,q\rangle =\int\limits_{-1}^{1} p(x)q(x)dx$ and consider the operator $Tp(x)=(1-x^2)p''(x)-2xp'(x) = [(1-x^2)p'(x)]'$.

Show that T is self-adjoint.

---

So far I have this:

$\langle p,T^*q\rangle =\langle Tp,q\rangle$

=$\langle(1-x^2)p''(x)-2xp'(x),q\rangle$

=$\int\limits_{-1}^{1} [(1-x^2)p'(x)]'q(x)dx$

Then I did integration by parts and got an answer that seems like it's not going to amount to anything. Is this a question which I should tackle by calculating the matrix of $T$ with respect to some basis and then taking the conjugate transpose to find $T^*$? If so, what basis should I use?

Comment: Hint. If you're trying to show self adjoint, how can you start your work with $⟨p,T^∗q⟩=⟨Tp,q⟩$?

Comment: what are the feature of P and Q

Comment: Remember that you can exploit the notion that $\langle p,T^*q\rangle -\langle Tp,q\rangle=0$ and begin to construct an integral around this.

Comment: Would explicitly writing out $p(x) = a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2$ and calculating what $T$ does to that base polynomial help me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have\begin{align}\bigl\langle T(p),q\bigr\rangle&=\int_{-1}^1\bigl((1-x^2)p'(x)\bigr)'q(x)\,\mathrm dx\\&=\bigl[\bigl((1-x^2)p'(x)\bigr)q(x)\bigr]_{x=-1}^{x=1}-\int_{-1}^1p'(x)(1-x^2)q(x)\,\mathrm dx\\&=-\int_{-1}^1p'(x)(1-x^2)q(x)\,\mathrm dx\\&=-\bigl[p(x)(1-x^2)q(x)\bigr]_{x=-1}^{x=1}+\int_{-1}^1p(x)\bigl((1-x^2)q(x)\bigr)'\,\mathrm dx\\&=0+\bigl\langle p,T(q)\bigr\rangle\\&=\bigl\langle p,T(q)\bigr\rangle.\end{align}Therefore, $T$ is self-adjoint.

Answer (score 2):

$$Tp(x)=(1-x^2)p''(x)-2xp'(x) = [(1-x^2)p'(x)]'$$

then by integration by part we get,
$$ \langle Tp,q\rangle = \int\limits_{-1}^{1} [(1-x^2)p'(x)]'q(x)dx \\=  \underbrace{[(1-x^2)p'(x)q(x)]^1_{-1} }_{=0}- \int\limits_{-1}^{1} (1-x^2)p'(x)q'(x)dx \\=-\int\limits_{-1}^{1} [(1-x^2)q'(x)] p'(x)dx$$

doing integration by part again we get

$$ \langle Tp,q\rangle =-\int\limits_{-1}^{1} [(1-x^2)q'(x)] p'(x)dx\\=-\underbrace{[(1-x^2)p(x)q'(x)]^1_{-1} }_{=0}  +\int\limits_{-1}^{1} [(1-x^2)q'(x)]' p(x)dx  =\langle Tq,p\rangle $$

that is $$ \langle Tp,q\rangle  =\langle Tq,p\rangle $$